# Difficulty in showing cart preview after successful ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want show cart preview on hover event on a particular div `shopbag`. For this what I've done is I've added one div `livebag` & inside I've added a query (because I store cart items into DB) to search for the items & preview them. Initially that div is hidden & on mouseover event div `livebag` is visible.
I've included addtocart facility directly into my search box & that item is added to the cart through ajax request, thus on a product addition, div `shopbag` is updated with newer total items present in cart.
Now when I attempt to show cart preview, it doesn't show updated data.
Here's my code:

**header.php**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('mouseenter','#shopbag',function(e){
    $("#livebag").css("display","block");
});
$(document).delegate('.buynow','click', function(e){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "addtocart.php",
    context: this,
    data: {type:type,quantity:quantity,productid:productid},
    success: function(option){
      $('#shopbag').empty();
      $('#shopbag').replaceWith(option);
    });
});
</script>
<body>
<?php
echo "<div id='shopbag'>Cart {$number}</div>";
echo "<div id='livebag'>";
$query="select * from cart";
foreach($query as $row){
echo $row['name'];
}
echo "</div>";
?>
</body>
```

**addtocart.php (ajax file)**

```
echo "<div id='shopbag'>Cart {$proInCart}</div>";
```

If we can refresh the div `livebag`, it can solve the issue, I guess. Any help in this?
![Image of Divisions][1]

Comment: What is `livebag`? Your code updates `shopbag`?

Comment: Div `livebag` is where I show the preview of cart items which is initially hidden but on hover event it should be made visible. Div `shopbag` is in header which has the count of cart items, on adding product, it will update the number only.

Comment: @ShanilSoni Do you use a seperate file for the contents of `livebag`? E.g. you have your livebag in your index file and shopbag is in shopbag.php which you then include?

Comment: Nope both are in header.php file only, wait I'm adding a screenshot which will be useful to you understanding the divisions.

Comment: You can have a look, all are in one file only, header.php

Comment: Could you add some additional HTML to show the actual structure? I'm not really following here

Comment: I've added some more info, hope it will be able to help you in getting clear picture.

Comment: @ShanilSoni Take a look at my answer, that should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I'd do the following:

Move the generation of the `livebag` div to a different file, but keep the actual div there. Include that file:

```
<div>
    <div id="shopbag">...</div>

    <div id="livebag">
        <?php include 'livebag.php'; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your `livebag.php` should then contain something like this:

```
<?php
...
...
...
$items = $con->query(...);

foreach($items as $item)
{
    echo '
    <div class="item">
    ...
    </div>';
}
```

When done with your request, do the following:

```
$("#livebag").load('livebag.php');
```

Please note that I don't know your HTML structure, so this is just something crude.

Take a look at the jquery [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function.

Comment: Loading content from external php file helped :)